# How to add the css class or id in the form for <tr>

Tags: magento-1.8, forms

Hi I am having problem  with Adminhtml form customization.
I am trying to hide the table row, but tr does not have any selector, so I am trying to add the selector to the table row.
I don't know how to add selectors.  If anyone know please help me.

Here is my Form

```
$form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $this->setForm($form);
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('storeadvertisement_form', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('advertisement')->__('Advertisement Media')));
        $fieldset->addType(
            'image',
            'Npm_Advertisement_Block_Adminhtml_Storeadvertisement_Helper_Image'
        );
        $fieldset->addField('url', 'text', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('advertisement')->__('Video URL'),
            'required'  => true,
            'style'     =>'display:none',
            'name'      => 'url',
            ));

        $fieldset->addField('link', 'text', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('advertisement')->__('Link'),
            'required'  => true,
            'name'      => 'link',
            'class'     =>  'validate-url'
        ));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do u want to hide it permanently or want to show it back on some action?

Comment: Yes Marius I want to show it back.here is my javascript code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a selector on the `<tr>` element.
You can identify the table row based on the input.
Let's say the input (or select or textarea) has the id `some_input`.
You can get the `tr` element like this:

```
var tr = $('some_input').up(1);
```

As a side note, you can get the `<td>` element like this:

```
var td = $('some_input').up();
```

Comment: I would like to give thumbs up, But i dont have reputation, Thank you so much. you save my time

Comment: @deSoul. No need for thumbs up. If this solved your issue, mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

you can add a selector to a row just by adding "container_id" in to the field's configuration options i.e ..

```
$fieldset->addField('url', 'text', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('advertisement')->__('Video URL'),
            'required'  => true,
            'style'     =>'display:none',
            'name'      => 'url',
            'container_id' => 'row-id',
));
```

this in turn will add an id to a tr (`<tr id="row-id">`) of the field.
hope it suffice.

Comment: Can we remove id from field(input,select.....etc)